# Excel select entire row(s) by cell contents and/or style

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to be able to select one or multiple rows where one column (specifically a country column) contains a certain value (such as selecting all rows where the country column contains 'India').

I also want to be able to select all rows that have a certain formatting (the default 'Good' style in Excel 2016.

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit to let us know what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps a macro is your best bet. Other than some special predefined values, Excel (unlike Word) does not include a native feature to select all items found by the *Find* tool.